# How could I handle the '\n' character in my console formatter and why it prints the text 'randomly'?

Tags: java, console-application, string-formatting

I'm trying to make a console formatter for my application and so far I've made it! But there are two big problems that I want to fix.

First: how do I handle the `\n` char in it?
and Second: Why it prints the text '*randomly*'?

So this is my code:

```
public synchronized void formattedLog(PrintStream stream, String message, String prefix, int consoleWidth, int fontWidth) {
    int maxCharsOnOneLine = consoleWidth / fontWidth;
    int maxCharsWithPrefix = maxCharsOnOneLine - prefix.length();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String toAppend = "";
    int charAt = 0;
    while (true) {

        String word = "";
        int charWordIndex = charAt + 1;
        if (message.charAt(charAt) == ' ' || charAt == 0) {
            if (charAt == 0) {
                word += message.charAt(0);
            }
            while (charWordIndex < message.length()) {
                char nextChar = message.charAt(charWordIndex);
                if (nextChar != ' ' && nextChar != '\n') {
                    word += nextChar;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                charWordIndex++;
            }
        }

        if (word != "") {
            if (word.length() <= maxCharsWithPrefix) {
                if ((toAppend + word).length() <= maxCharsWithPrefix) {
                    toAppend += word + " ";
                } else {
                    builder.append(prefix);
                    builder.append(toAppend);
                    builder.append("\n");
                    toAppend = "";
                    toAppend += word + " ";
                }
            } else {
                int wordChar = 0;
                toAppend += "";
                while (true) {
                    if (toAppend.length() < maxCharsWithPrefix) {
                        if (wordChar < word.length()) toAppend += word.charAt(wordChar);
                    } else {
                        builder.append(prefix);
                        builder.append(toAppend);
                        builder.append("\n");
                        toAppend = "";
                        toAppend += word.charAt(wordChar);
                    }

                    wordChar++;

                    if (wordChar >= word.length()) {
                        toAppend += " ";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        charAt++;

        if (charAt >= message.length()) {
            builder.append(prefix);
            builder.append(toAppend);
            builder.append("\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    stream.println(builder.toString());
}
```

First: Now it does not 'parse' the strings with \n in it, but if it would it would look like this:

```
LOG> Text (\n)
Other text
LOG> ...
```

And I don't want that. I want it to print

```
LOG> Text (\n)
LOG> Other Text
LOG> ...
```

How could I achieve this?

And second by random I mean this:

I have this simple code to try the thing out; here it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    consoleFormatter = new ConsoleFormatter();


    consoleFormatter.logDefault("This is a long text to try the functionality of the method. This is literally ", "LOG> ", 600);
    consoleFormatter.logDefault("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee test words words words", "LOG> ", 200);
    try {
        throwFakeExecption(new NullPointerException("Fake null pointer exception."));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        consoleFormatter.logError(e.toString(), "ERROR> ", 1000);
        consoleFormatter.logError(e.getStackTrace()[0].toString(), "ERROR> ", 1000);
    }

}

public static void throwFakeExecption(Exception ex) throws Exception {
    throw ex;
}
```

Sometimes it prints it like this:

[image]

Other times like this:[image]

And even other times like this:[image]

I want the text to be in order and I don't know why it is doing that.

How could I fix these two problems?

Comment: Have you tired explicitly flushing the PrintStream after writing each log entry?

Comment: @dnault nothing's changed.

Comment: Then I guess you're stuck. The stdout and stderr streams are independent of one another; if you really need a deterministic order, you'll have to write to only one stream (either System.out *or* System.err, but not both).